# higher or lower game unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

need help with a higher or lower game I think the problem has something to do with the loop. I have been told been told to add an except but I have no idea where to add it

```
print('Welcome to higher or lower game')

input('press enter to start.\n')

import random
Max = 10
Min = 0

num = random.randint(1, 10)

print('your starting number is a ' + str(num))

while 'well done.\n' :

guess = input('higher (h) or lower (l).\n')

new_num = random.randint(1, 10)

print('your new number is a ' + str (new_num))

try :
   if new_num > num and guess == 'h':
    print('well done.\n')
   elif new_num < num and guess == 'l':
    print('well done.\n')
    break

  if num and guess == 'l' and new_num > num and guess:
   print('game over')
  elif num and guess == 'h' and new_num < num and guess:
   print('game over')
  else:
   print('game over you got a score of ' + str(score))
```

Comment: Please paste your code in the question instead of an image

Comment: Every `try` statement must be matched by either an `except` or a `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an `except` clause in the `try` statement. That clause is required unless you have a `finally` clause.

Comment: `except` is only required if `finally` is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have a try statement there. You could take it out and just go with some if and elif statements.

Example:

```py
import random
number = random.randint(1,10)
lives = 3
Success = False
while lives > 0:
    guess = int(input("What is your guess between 1 and 10? \r\n"))
    if guess > number:
        print("Too high! Go lower. \r\n")
        lives -= 1
    elif guess < number:
        print("Too low! Go higher. \r\n")
        lives -= 1
    elif guess == number:
        print("Congratulations, you win!")
        global Success = True
        break
if Success != True:
    print("Sorry. Try again!  The number was ", number, ".")
```

As far as I understand, try statements are mainly used for error handling.